# C# - Nesting Generics without Specifying 'T' in the Encapsulating Class

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to create a group of classes that represents data being recorded and their relation to events they trigger. A `Data` class represents the recorded data. The data values can vary in type. i.e. string, bool, int, float. Thus, I reason a generic class may be useful here.

**Data.cs**

```
public class Data<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public string Units { get; set; }
}
```

Data is then captured as an array and encapsulated based on a context of which they were collected. We refer to this as a parameter in this case and includes the data array but also additional details about what recorded the data.

**Parameter.cs**

```
public class Parameter<T> 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //...

    public Data<T>[] Data { get; set; }
    
}
```

This works in this case because Parameters will only have data of the same type. Where this gets tricky is when I want to associate parameters with triggers. Triggers consist of multiple parameters that can be of varying data types. In this case I cannot simply push the  attribute to the trigger level..

**Trigger.cs** (Not Going to work)

```
public class Trigger<T> 
{
    //...
    public Parameters<T>[] Data { get; set; }

}
```

So my question is this... What would the best practice be to abstract T away at the Trigger level.

I though about an empty interface of IParameter but this seems like a hack rather than the right way to do this.

**IParameter.cs**

```
public class IParameter 
{

}
```

**Trigger.cs**

```
public class Trigger
{
    //...

    public IParameter[] Parameters {get;set;}

}
```

Comment: "Triggers consist of multiple parameters that can be of varying data types." Then it's not generic. You're going to need some non-generic type (e.g. your interface) if you want to store them in an array. But then you won't know the type of each parameter at compile-time.

Comment: DStanley is right, I suspect in order for this to work you are going to end up using reflection rather than generics. Have a look at the many variants of `Action<T1>`, `Action<T1,T2>`, `Action<T1,T2,T3>` and you'll see another problem with trying to enforce the types at compile time. Your last suggestion would work, it would be convenient to provide the parameter's type as a proeprty: `public interface IParameter { Type ParameterType { get; } }`

Comment: string, bool, int, float are all of type `object` so why not just use `object` and not generics? I don't see that you are using any properties or methods not supported by object class

Comment: This feels like you are building an "inner platform" anti-pattern. How about pushing the parameter definition down to the implementation type of each trigger. `public class ThisTrigger : Trigger { Data<int> Arg1 { get; set; } ... }`